# How do I place the same label multiple times in a GUI window (using tkinter)?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written a couple GUI programs in Python using tkinter. For several of them, I added an "ADD" button, which when pressed, it adds a new row of widgets to the window. Since coding this can be time consuming, I created a class with a method that functions to add the row of widgets. However, when I tested it out, it doesn't work properly. Once I add the first row of widgets, any subsequent row I add seems to just be placed over the previous one. My code is provided below:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Row:
   def __init__(self, name, row_widgets):
       self.name = name
       self.row_widgets = row_widgets

   def add(self, previous_row_no, column_start_no, widget_rows):
       row_no = previous_row_no + 1
       column_no = column_start_no
       widgs = []
       for widget in self.row_widgets:
           widget.grid(column=column_no, row=row_no)
           column_no += 1
           widgs.append(widget)
       widget_rows.append(widgs)
       return row_no, widget_rows


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')

widgrows = []
label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Label 1')
label2 = tk.Label(root, text='Label 2')
label3 = tk.Label(root, text='Label 3')
row1_widgets = [label1, label2, label3]
row1 = Row('row1', row1_widgets)

# Add 3 rows of widgets
row1.add(0, 0, widgrows)
row1.add(1, 0, widgrows)
row1.add(2, 0, widgrows)

root.mainloop()
```

This code produces the following window, with only one row of widgets:

[Created Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fe6Ir.png)

However, I want 3 rows of widgets, as shown in the following figure:

[Desired Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deeNN.png)

It seems that the problem is that every time I use the add method, it is using the same widgets. For example, the first time I use the add method, it takes label1 and places it in row 1, column 0. Next time I use the add method, it's as if it takes label1 out of row 1 and places it into row 2. I'm pretty new to Python, so I'm not sure if this is what is going on, but after some experimenting it is what seems to be happening.

Any ideas on how to get this to work properly without having to create multiple labels with the same text?

Comment: It's not working because each time you use `grid`, it is on the same widgets from before. You are not creating any new widgets. You are just repositioning them.

Comment: if the class is named `Row` I would expect it to represent a singular row, also meaning there either shouldn't be a method to add rows or it should be allowed to be called only once, otherwise you are running into this problem, you could still run into it but first at least remove the `.add_row` method and place the functionality in the `__init__` method (IMO), then just create each row using `Row` class and add a new list of widgets to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a slightly less complicated way of achieving the desired results.

`Labels` can be created in varying numbers of row and columns, each one has it's own name and they are stored in `rows.row_widgets`

I've removed `root.geometry` in order to allow `tkinter` to calculate the necessary window size.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Row:

    def __init__(self, master, name):
        self.master = master
        self.name = name
        self.row_widgets = []

    def add(self, text, r = 0, c = 0, s = "nsew"):
        L = tk.Label(self.master, text=text)
        L.grid(row = r, column = c, sticky = s)
        self.row_widgets.append(L)

root = tk.Tk()
# root.geometry('200x200')

rows = Row(root, 'row')

i = 0
for r in range(4):
    for c in range(4):
        rows.add(f'Label_{i:02}', r = r, c = c)
        i = i + 1

for labels in rows.row_widgets:
    print(labels["text"])

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create each label or make copies of those 3 labels. Something like this:

```
widgrows = []
row1 = None
for j in range(3):
    labels = []
    for i in range(3):
        label = tk.Label(root, text=f'Label {i}')
        labels.append(label)
    if not row1:
        row1 = Row('row1', labels)
    else:
        row1.row_widgets = labels
    row1.add(j, 0, widgrows)
```